# Ignoring similar columns when concating matrixes vertically

Tags: matlab, matrix, distance, similarity, concatenation

In matlab I have a 128 by n matrix, which we can call

> [A B C]

where each letter is an 128 by 1 matrix.

So what I want to do is concat the above matrix with another matrix,

> [A~ D E].

Where A~ is similar in its values to A. 
 What I want to get as the result of the concat would be:

> [A B C D E],

where A~ is omitted.

What is the best way to do this? Note that I do not know beforehand that A~ is similar.

To clarify, my problem is how would I determine if two columns are similar? By similar I mean where between two columns, many of the row values are close in value.

Maybe an illustration would help as well

```
Vector A: [1  2   3 4 5 6 7 8   9]'
           |  |   | | | | | |   | 
Vector B: [20 2.4 4 5 0 7 7 7.6 10]'
```

where there are some instances where the values are completely different, but for the most part the values are close. I don't have a defined threshold for this, but ideally it would be something that I could experiment with.

Comment: Is your question a) how to determine if A~ is similar to A; b) how to grab only two columns of a matrix; or c) something else entirely?

Comment: What do you mean with 'similar'? If it's not **identical** what you mean, then you should define some way to define 'similar enough to be omitted' so that your question can be answered.

Comment: @tmpearce I have updated the question, please take a look now

Comment: @mugetsu If, say, you want to find whether `A` and `B` are similar matrices or not, why not just do: `is_similar = all(abs(A(:) - B(:)) < some_threshold)`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To solve this, a matching algorithm called vl_ubcmatch can be used.

> [matches, scores] = vl_ubcmatch(da, db) ; For each descriptor in da,
>   vl_ubcmatch finds the closest descriptor in db (as measured by the L2
>   norm of the difference between them). The index of the original match
>   and the closest descriptor is stored in each column of matches and the
>   distance between the pair is stored in scores.

source:
http://www.vlfeat.org/overview/sift.html

Thus, the solution is to find the matched columns with the highest scores and eliminate them before concatenating.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to omit only **identical** columns, this is one way to do it:

```
%# Define the example matrices.

Matrix1 = [ 1 2 3; 4 5 6; 7 8 9 ]';

Matrix2 = [ 4 5 6; 7 8 10 ]';

%# Concatenate the matrices and keep only unique columns.

OutputMatrix = unique([ Matrix1, Matrix2 ]', 'rows')';
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it's `pdist2` you need. 
Consider the following example:

```
>> X = rand(25, 5); 
>> Y = rand(100, 5); 
>> Y(22, : ) = 0.99*X(22,:); 
>> D = pdist2(X,Y, 'euclidean'); 
>> [~,ind] = min(D(:)); 
>> [i,j]=ind2sub(size(D),ind)

    i = 
        22
    j = 
        22
```

which is indeed the entry we manipulated to be similar. Read `help pdist2` or `doc pdist2` for more background.